# predicting lmer models with equal baselines

Tags: r, predict, lme4

I have an lmer model, modelstatus based on a dataset, EM6. I created a new variable in EM6 based on the predicted values from the model:

> modelstatus<-lmer(MS_TOT~acstatus2+ExamStage+acstatus2*ExamStage+AIS.1+Level.1+MS_TOT.1+I+(ExamStage|id), EM6

So my outcome variable is a motor score (MS_TOT, which generally improves over time). ExamStage is time (in months). My treatment of interest is acstatus2 (= 0, 1, or 2). I also controlled for their baseline motor score (MS_TOT.1). I then found the predicted values of this score:

```
EM6$predictedvalues<-predict(modelstatus, EM6)

View(EM6$predictedvalues)
```

I then wanted to see these predicted values based on the treatment group (acstatus2) and time variable (ExamStage, in months) so I did:

```
 summaryBy(EM6$predictedvalues~EM6$acstatus2 + EM6$ExamStage, data=EM6, FUN=c(median, IQR, length2), na.rm=TRUE)
   acstatus2 ExamStage EM6$predictedvalues.median EM6$predictedvalues.IQR
1          0         1                   48.77660                27.32741
2          0         3                   54.54813                29.61648
3          0         6                   59.89441                33.93366
4          0        12                   59.22905                40.97660
5          1         1                   49.80685                22.90928
6          1         3                   52.69312                24.33251
7          1         6                   57.18737                28.29565
8          1        12                   62.65427                34.99713
9          2         1                   62.06621                39.99068
10         2         3                   68.71611                41.33236
11         2         6                   82.55019                41.42683
12         2        12                   84.66000                42.58164
```

However, as you can see, the baselines predicted values (at ExamStage=1) between the three treatment groups differ greatly (48.78, 49.81, 62.07). What I WANT to do is this exact comparison, btu with equal baseline values (i.e. if held constant, what is the effect of treatment 0, 1, or 2?). Is this possible?

Thanks!!

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what's going on here because you haven't given any details about your model. But depending on how your model was fit, you should be able to get an estimate of the treatment effect controlling for baseline levels through the fixed effect coefficient for `acstatus2` (unless I'm missing something, which is entirely possible).

Comment: I tried to clarify my post a bit- does that help? Thank you!

Comment: So it looks like you're fitting a growth model where `ExamStage` represents your linear growth rate, and you're trying to see if there's an initial difference between treatment groups and/or if the rate of growth differs among groups, is that right? Is `ExamStage` coded so that 0 is meaningful? (I would, if not). I guess overall I'm confused as to why you're looking at predicted values, rather than the coefficients. Also, is `acstatus2` defined as a factor so you're estimating separate parameters for each group?